# How does GDB halt execution of the other process? How does GDB work?

Tags: gdb

I am looking for some information on how GDB access a running processes environment and symbols; e.g. how it works and how it halts the execution of the program.

Answer (score 2):

gdb uses the `ptrace` system call. Read the manual page to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

There is [GDB Internals Manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/Internals). It covers internals of gdb and describes it's key algorithms and operations.

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: @Pharap, updated the link to GDB wiki derived from the old GDB Internals Manual which is now retired.